# Hide JSON content while loading

Tags: jquery, json, preload

I'm trying to hide my dynamically filled content div (#photographs) while it is being filled by JSON.

```
$(window).load(function() { 

$("#loader").fadeIn("fast");

$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=' + photoset_id + '&per_page=1000' + '&page=1' + '&api_key=' + apiKey + '&user_id=' + userId + '&jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    var fullPhotoURL, flickrLink;

    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, flickrPhoto){
        var basePhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_z.jpg";  

        var fullPhotoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/'
        + flickrPhoto.server + '/' + flickrPhoto.id + '_' + flickrPhoto.secret + "_l.jpg";          

        $("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURL).appendTo("#photographs").wrap(("<div class='item'></div>"))
    });

    $("#loader").fadeOut("fast");

});
});
```

The above of course works to some extent. The loading animation (#loader) fades in on load, and fades out when the JSON call has **started**. What i need, is that while loading, the pictures won't show (so set the #photographs on display: none?), and **after** everything has loaded, the #loader fades out (and the pictures too of course).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not using the `each` iteration inside `$.ajax`'s GET callback?

Comment: Is it not already in the json callback? I'm a bit confused; do you mean the 'success' in the JSON call?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wait appending the img tags to the #photographs until you loaded all photos?

E.g.

```
$.getJSON(...) {
  var images = [];

  $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i, flickrPhoto){
     ...
     images.push($("<img/>").attr("src", basePhotoURL));
  });
  $.each(images, function(index, img) {
     img.appendTo("#photographs").wrap(("<div class='item'></div>"));
  });
});
```

Comment: This looks to be the better solution. Only firebug says "img.appendTo is not a function".

Comment: Sorry, should have been ... $.each(images, function(index, img) { ... (added index to the function params). Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. All my images are still visibly loading in (slowly); even worse, adding a photographs div fadeIn fadeOut switch doesn't have any effect either..